# Is it possible to flash MB BIOS pre CPU POST?

Tags: gaming, motherboard, pc

I have a motherboard here that won't complete POST. Stripped it down to just CPU, MB, 1 DDR4 chip. The old board had a bent pin which I did not notice until after I broke it down when POST was failing, so I got a new MB, but same issue. Many are saying it needs a BIOS update. If so, is it even possible to update the BIOS? I have a USB with BIOS files on it here. Is it possible the CPU got hosed being set into a bent pin?

MB: Gigabyte Aorus X299 gaming 7
CPU: Intel i9 7900x
RAM: Ballistix Sport LT DDR4 2400 MT/s (PC4-19200)

Comment: What is the appropriate board for this topic? Oop, just saw it - super user. thanks.